# Stripping Down VS 2008 Win32 DLL to one file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winapi

I have a VS generated C++ Win32 DLL project.  It has the following files:

stdafx.h
targetver.h
myProject.h
dllmain.cpp
myProject.cpp
stdafx.cpp

I can remove targetver.h, and merge dllmain.cpp into myProject.cpp.  What more can I do to get the simplest file structure, preferably one file.  I need to dynamically emit this code file and build it into a Win32 DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a minimalistic file structure, you could just create the files yourself. Start an empty project, or delete all the files. Heck, just make a folder, write main.cpp, and [compile it from the command line with cl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639.aspx).

Few IDEs really try to minimize files like you're trying to -- but when you create the project, you can cut back a little: stdafx.[h, cpp] are for precompiled headers, which you could disable when creating the project.

That said, I don't really see the value in minimizing the amount of source code in a compiled language project -- it's not going to have a meaningful impact on the number of output files/dlls and, properly used, using more files only helps your code's clarity.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Andy said, you can merge the `myProject` header and implementation files as well with `dllmain.cpp`. But why not just keep these files and create the vsproj file at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just create an empty project.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, `myProject.h` and `myProject.cpp` both contain an example of an exported class. You can easily delete those.

`stdafx.cpp` and `stdafx.h` are used for the standard precompiled header file. If you turn off the setting that requires a precompiled header, then those files won't be necessary, either.

Answer (score 0):

You could #include your generated file into a existing multi-file project. That way you can have a shell of a complicated project and only emit something smaller, like a simple function.

For example:

```
#include <system_stuff>

void main()
{
   Go();
}

#include "generated_file_that_has_method_go.cpp"

void other_code()
{
}
```